# Is there a scale unit between thousand and million which is in one word?

Tags: measuring-units

10^2 is a hundred. 10^3 is a thousand. 10^6 is a million.

Is there a scale unit for 10^4, 10^5 or others?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_10

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a scale unit for 10^4, 10^5?

No. Not in British or American English.

> or others

Yes. See the link provided by Stuart F -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_10

Note that **Myriad** is not used as a unit and **Lakh** is only used on the Indian Subcontinent.